# How to extract data from dataframe in pandas and assign them to normal variables

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get individual data from groupby() function result in pandas and assign them to variables, but i dont know how:
for example:

```
df

    Names    Grades    Ages
0   Bob       4        20
1   Jessica   3        21
3   Bob       3        22
4   John      2        20
5   Bob       4        24

print(df.groupby('Names').Ages.mean())

Names
Bob       33
Jessica   21
John      20
```

Now i want get the mean value of Bob into a scalar variable, like:
`Bob_mean = 33` <-- how to extract this value from the dataframe object in pandas

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: `s.loc['Bob']` where `s` is your series, or just `s['Bob']`

Comment: Notice that you don't _need_ to have separate variables to be able to use the values in the series. You can just plug `s['Bob']` wherever you were going to plug `Bob_mean` directly.

Comment: What did you actually try? This is extremely basic Pandas functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Bob', 4,  20],
                   ['Jessica', 3,  21],
                   ['Bob', 3, 22],
                   ['John', 2, 20],
                   ['Bob', 4, 24]], columns=['Names', 'Grades', 'Ages'])

bob_mean = df.groupby(by = 'Names').Ages.mean()['Bob']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

Simply amend your code to select the index 'Bob':

```
df.groupby('Names').Ages.mean()['Bob']
```

However groupby operations can become very slow and instead we can use df.loc:

```
df.loc[df['Names']=='Bob'].Ages.mean()
```

Comment: Thanks for the bonus way of df.loc.

Comment: Please accept one answer so the question can be labeled as answered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers